# MidiSystem.start() makes no sound

Tags: java, audio

Im new to java and im creating a test application demonstrating creating sounds. i have this test code:

```
public class MiniMiniMusicApp {

    public MiniMiniMusicApp(){

    }

    public void play(){
        try{
            Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            player.open();

            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);

            Track track = seq.createTrack();

            ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(144,1,20,100);
            MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a, 1);
            track.add(noteOn);

            ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(128, 1, 44, 100);
            MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b, 3);
            track.add(noteOn);

            Track[] t = seq.getTracks();
            player.setSequence(seq);

            player.start();

            System.out.println("Done");
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Ooops something went wrong");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and i can hear no sound. I've read somewhere that i need a soundbank, so i downloaded the deluxe version from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/soundbanks-135798.html#download) and i have copied it into C:\Program File\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib created a folder called audio and copied soundbank.gm in there. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment on the question - but do you mean to have this line

```
track.add(noteOn);
```

in there twice?

Also you call

```
a.setMessage(...)
```

twice.

There's a couple of other strange things going on, creating an array that's never used etc.

I suggest cleaning up your code a little.

Comment: man how come i didnt notice... that was it, thank you! Here have some repu :)